# Short cut for incremental averages

Tags: excel, average

In Excel I have 200 columns of data and I would like to take the average of each of the columns. However I need to do it in a very specific way. For the first column, I just need the average of the first entry. For the second column, I need the average of the first two entries. For the third column, I need the average of the first three entries etc.

Essentially, I would like my formula to read like this (the '-' represent breaks between cells)

=average(A1:A1) - =average(B1:B2) - =average(C1:C3) - =average(D1:D4) - . . .

Is there a formula to do this so I don't have to do it by hand for each individual column?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for column `A`, and copy across for as many columns as required

```
=AVERAGE(A1:INDEX(A:A,COLUMN(A1)))
```

Comment: Actually just found a solution myself. Never used this command before, "offset". Anyway, the formula is =AVERAGE(A1:OFFSET(A1,A50,0)) where A50 is defined as 0 but it increments by 1 as you go to B50, C50, D50. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad you solved it.  My formula offers several advantages: It's not _Volatile_ , as `Offset` is.  It doesn't rely on extra data on the sheet (although you could use `COLUMN()` in yours too)

Comment: I never really use INDEX because all the info required after the command always confuses me! But if you say it is less volatile it is probably worth my while learning it. Also, I'm new to stack overflow (though I use Exchange), how do I put commands in grey boxes?

Comment: A function either _is_ or _is not_ volitile, there's no more or less volitile.  To better understand what this means see [Charles Williams' site](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm).  As to the "Grey Box", it's `Code Format` Add it by indenting with 4 spaces, enclosing in `` (back tick) marks, or use the { } button